# numpy.fromfile is reading only 1st row

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to read tabular data using

> numpy.fromfile()

for its fast speed,but its only reading the first row. 
How to read the entire table?
I don't want to use pandas or numpy.loadtext()

```
np.fromfile('abc.txt', count=-1,  sep=",")
```

Comment: why not loadtxt? How does your file look in detail?

Comment: loadtext take more time. my file is around 2GB in size with 8 columns

Comment: if you have several lines, it cannot work with your separator "," because this one obviously only separates the columns, but what separates the line is a newline character (`chr(10)` or `chr(13)`). Therefore fromfile is not flexible enough for you data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can read a white-space separated multiline file:

```
In [312]: cat mytest.txt
      0.26       0.63       0.97       1.01       0.42
      1.66       1.54       1.07       2.13       1.44
      2.57       2.73       2.45       2.47       2.29
      3.75       3.91       3.37       3.32       4.32
      4.27       4.33       4.05       4.21       4.48
      0.37       0.58       0.07       0.59       0.48
      2.17       1.99       1.61       1.30       2.09
      2.82       2.08       2.39       2.48       2.51
      3.12       3.36       2.76       3.62       3.25
      4.24       4.97       4.51       4.25       4.65
      0.42       0.03       0.29       0.10       0.46
      1.11       2.05       1.40       1.86       1.36
      2.07       2.16       2.81       2.47       2.37
      3.65       3.25       3.60       3.23       3.80
      4.23       3.75       4.67       4.34       4.78
In [313]: np.fromfile('mytest.txt',count=-1,dtype=float,sep=' ')
Out[313]: 
array([ 0.26,  0.63,  0.97,  1.01,  0.42,  1.66,  1.54,  1.07,  2.13,
        1.44,  2.57,  2.73,  2.45,  2.47,  2.29,  3.75,  3.91,  3.37,
        3.32,  4.32,  4.27,  4.33,  4.05,  4.21,  4.48,  0.37,  0.58,
        0.07,  0.59,  0.48,  2.17,  1.99,  1.61,  1.3 ,  2.09,  2.82,
        2.08,  2.39,  2.48,  2.51,  3.12,  3.36,  2.76,  3.62,  3.25,
        4.24,  4.97,  4.51,  4.25,  4.65,  0.42,  0.03,  0.29,  0.1 ,
        0.46,  1.11,  2.05,  1.4 ,  1.86,  1.36,  2.07,  2.16,  2.81,
        2.47,  2.37,  3.65,  3.25,  3.6 ,  3.23,  3.8 ,  4.23,  3.75,
        4.67,  4.34,  4.78])
```

The newline is treated as just another white space.

But a `,` delimited file does not cross line boundaries

```
In [315]: cat test.txt
 -0.22424938,   0.16117005,  -0.39249256
 -0.22424938,   0.16050598,  -0.39249256
 -0.22424938,   0.15984190,  -0.39249256
  0.09214371,  -0.26184322,  -0.39249256
  0.09214371,  -0.26250729,  -0.39249256
  0.09214371,  -0.26317136,  -0.39249256
In [316]: np.fromfile('test.txt',count=-1,dtype=float,sep=',')
Out[316]: array([-0.22424938,  0.16117005, -0.39249256])
```

`loadtxt` and `genfromtxt` are designed for tabular data.  Yes they are slow, reading the file line by line.  But they have a lot more flexibility.  `pandas` has a faster csv reader.

Speed test for that ws delimited file:

```
In [319]: timeit np.loadtxt('mytest.txt')
1000 loops, best of 3: 623 µs per loop
In [320]: timeit np.fromfile('mytest.txt',count=-1,dtype=float,sep=' ')
The slowest run took 4.90 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 174 µs per loop
```